# How can I set x-www-form-urlencoded in SoapUI?

Tags: web-services, rest, soapui, stress-testing, loadui

I cannot see the media type x-www-form-urlencoded in SoapUI pro 5.0.0. How can I set this for a post method?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should write "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in Media type.

You can edit the text field.

Comment: THANKS we can really edit it and it's taken into account...

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Hope this will help you.Just focus on the highlighted areas